# Order Pricebook2Id to manage with multiple Order Product Pricebooks

Tags: pricebook, order, pricebookentry, orderitem

Scenario: There are multiple Order Products with different Pricebook(Year wise Pricebook) to be added on Order Object. But, on Order Object we can only set a single Pricebook Id.

Can anyone please give a workaround to deal with this situation?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

SFDC mandates that all `OrderItem`, `OpportunityLineItem`, `QuoteLineItem` share the same pricebook as their parent `Order`, `Opportunity`, `Quote` SObjects, resp.

Given it is a requirement for you (though I'd question it) that a given Order can include OrderItems from 2+ year's pricebooks, let's consider how to do this:

```
Product2    PBE    Pricebook
--------    ---    ---------
  S         $19      2019
  S         $20      2020
  T         $119     2019
  T         $120     2020
```

The 2020 Order needs to have

```
  S from 2019 pricebook ($19)
  T from 2020 pricebook ($120)
```

The business solution to this is simply to use the Pricebook for the current year (2020) and adjust the UnitPrice in the `S` OrderItem from $20 to $19. That is, if the business wants to discount the price of `S` to its 2019 value, then discount the price on the order.

Otherwise, you have to create synthetic SKUs in your product catalog like this:

```
Product2    PBE    Pricebook
--------    ---    ---------
  S         $19      2019
  S         $20      2020
  S-2019    $19      2020
  T         $119     2019
  T         $120     2020
```

and have the order be for two SKUs - `S-2019` and `T`, both from Order's Pricebook 2020.